# Организация базы данных с множеством параметров

Tags: база-данных, организация

Есть данные с большим количеством параметров (100+). При этом некоторые из параметров представляются в виде структур, некоторые в виде массивов. Из 15000 наборов данных лишь 25 из опций встречаются в более чем 100 наборов. Ещё 25 встречаются от 1 до 100 раз оставшиеся параметры ещё более редки. Подскажите, как подойти к организации данных, предполагается реализовывать на posql, но могут быть рассмотрены иные СУБД, предполагаемое количество записей <250 000.

Comment: Наверное следует отталкиваться от операций, которые чаще всего будут происходить с этими данными. Как часто будет происходить добавление новых, изменение, поиск?

Comment: Изменение не предполагается. Добавление по наступлению некого нечастого события, раз в час, а то и ещё реже. Предполагается ещё и формирования из записей бд некоторых данных.